# Install BackTrack 5 rc1 on Mac OSX Lion, feasable?

Tags: mac, boot-camp, multi-boot, backtrack

I just uninstalled windows from my bootcamp and i would like to run only my Lion and a second partition with BackTrack 5, is it doable?

I already tried to follow a couple tutorials i found around here and there, and all of them asked to partition my mac with bootcamp and then instal rEFIt, but this isn't possible on LION since when i try to partition my HD it asks for a Windows Installation disk..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mac's disk utility to shrink your hard drive - leaving enough empty space for your installation. Restart holding C and boot the live cd. Once it's up, it probably won't load the GUI unless you open stealth mode. Once into the GUI, install picking the 'install on largest free space' option and hit advanced to include a bootloader - which will enable you to dual boot.

This has worked for me to get it installed but I can't yet get the GUI running on the install - command line only so far.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% certain with regards to Lion, though, I did have Trisquel GNU/Linux installed side-by-side with Snow Leopard **without** refit. It is all a matter of GRUB, if the version of GRUB accompanying the Distribution of your choice is compiled with support for EFI, it should theoretically install side-by-side with Lion. The process would be identical to installing GNU/Linux side-by-side with any other operating system.

1. Boot GNU/Linux Live Distro via CD (I believe USB boot is not possible under the MBP)
2. Follow the Installer; when your asked about partitions you will have the option to install side-by-side, usually with a graphical slider of some sort.

You may also wish to ask about the *installation* process for BackTrack 5 with regards to the MacBook Pro on the BackTrack forums themselves; I have witnessed working examples of BT5 RC1 on a MBP, sans ReFIT.